# Fire fbq event with user_data

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-conversions-api

In FB doc, it is explained how to bind `user_data` to `fbq` while initializing fbq. However it is not explained how to bind `user_data` later on.

Let's say I have a form where users put their email. When the user hit "send" I call `fbq("trackCustom", "my_event")`, is there a way to make FB know customer's email so it can performed advanced matching?

I was thinking of maybe this:

```
fbq("trackCustom", "my_event", {user_data: {em: hash256("email")}})
```

Or this

```
fbq("setUserData", {em: hash256("email")});
fbq("trackCustom", "my_event");
```

But no way to find the right answer on Google.